# Getting remove button to work Java Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have one servlet which is called LeggTilHandlekurv (shoppingCart), one jsp, and one Vare (Item) class. The meaning is to add items to a shoppingCart and that is working well, but the question is how can I get the delete function to work? In leggtilhandlekurv.jsp you have the options to type in an item and the item will be displayed with a remove button. And I want the remove button to work. My try so far is in the servlet class marked out, starting from if(vare.equals("remove")).

```
@WebServlet("/"+LEGGTILHANDLEKURV_URL)
public class LeggTilHandlekurv extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
   
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("leggtilhandlekurv.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();
    String varen=request.getParameter("vare");
    
    Vare vare=new Vare();
    vare.setVareNavn(varen);
    

     
    ArrayList<Vare> varer = new ArrayList<Vare>();
    varer.add(vare);
    if(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("handlekurv")!=null) {
        varer=(ArrayList<Vare>) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("handlekurv");
        varer.add(vare);
        request.getServletContext().setAttribute("handlekurv", varer);
    }
    else {
        request.getServletContext().setAttribute("handlekurv", varer);
        
    }
    response.sendRedirect("leggtilhandlekurv.jsp");

/*  
    if(vare.equals("remove")) {
        varer=(ArrayList<Vare>) session.getAttribute("handlekurv");
        varer.remove(vare);
        session.setAttribute("handlekurv", varer);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("leggtilhandlekurv.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    }
    */
    }

}
```

```
public class Vare {
    
    private String vareNavn;

    public String getVareNavn() {
        return vareNavn;
    }

    public void setVareNavn(String vareNavn) {
        this.vareNavn=vareNavn;
    }
}
```

```
<%@page import="oppgave1.Vare"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Handleliste</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
if(session.getAttribute("pass")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>

<h1>Min handleliste</h1>


<form action="LeggTilHandlekurv" method="post">
        Legg til vare:  <br>
     <input type="text" name="vare"> <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Add item">
</form>
<table>
<th>Varer</th>

<%
ArrayList<Vare> varer = new ArrayList<Vare>();
if(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("handlekurv")!=null){
    varer=(ArrayList<Vare>) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("handlekurv");
if(!varer.isEmpty()){
    for(Vare vare: varer){
        
    
    %>
    <tr>
    <td> <%=vare.getVareNavn() %></td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove item"> </td>
    </tr>
<%
    }

    }

}

%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden input field which will have value of `vareNavn`and form tag which will submit your form to servlet and get response back . So , your **jsp** code will look like below :

```
<td>
    <form action="LeggTilHandlekurv" method="post">
       <!-- hidden input-->
       <input type="text" hidden name="item" value="<%=vare.getVareNavn() %>">
       <!--added name attribute-->
       <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove item"> 
    </form>
  </td>
```

Then , in you servlet `doPost` method you need to get the hidden input value i.e `item` and then compare this value with the values store in `session` if matches we just need to remove that value from session . So, your `doPost` method code will look like below :

```
//check if request is for remove
if (request.getParameter("remove") != null) {
  //get values
  String item = request.getParameter("item");
  //get data from session
  ArrayList<Vare> varer1 = (ArrayList<Vare>) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("handlekurv");

  Iterator<Vare> it = varer1.iterator();
  //iterate through datas
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Vare name = it.next();
    //check if values matches
    if (name.getVareNavn().equals(item)) {
      it.remove(); //remove
    }
  }
  //pass updated value to jsp page
  session.setAttribute("handlekurv", varer1);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("leggtilhandlekurv.jsp").forward(request, response); 
  }
```

Also , give *name* attribute here `<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add item">` as well and put your all code for adding new values inside  `if(request.getParameter("add") != null){ //put code here }`

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me, should I substitute your jsp code with <td> <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove item"> </td> and also when switching to if(request.getParameter("add") != null) the code will not work when I have all the adding inside the if statement. Is there something I should delete from the adding code?

Comment: I have use `form` inside td because when you will click on submit button so only the value which is inside form will get submitted.Also , these codes are already tested . I just added `if(request.getParameter("add") != null) ..` around add codes it was working fine on my end .

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I forgot to add if(request.getParameter("add") != null) around the add code.